# Build Expression To sort based on the order of array

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I'm trying to build an expression to sort based on the order of an values passed in an array.  I have most of the concept down but I'm confused on how I can select the expressions to chain the ternaries together.

```
/// <summary>
/// This method will build an expression to map the order 
/// of the ownerkeys to it's index to use for sorting
/// I.E I have an array [DivisionOwnerGuid, CompanyOwnerGuid]
/// ownerKey == {DivisionOwnerGuid} ? 0
/// ownerKey == {CompanyOwnerGuid} ? 1 : Int32.MaxValue
/// </summary>
protected Expression<Func<IConfigurationValue, int>> GetOrderByExpression(
    guid[] ownerKeyByPriority)
{

    // x =>
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IConfigurationValue));
    ownerKeyByPriority.Select((ownerKey, index) => new {
        // Hack: Build the expressions using the same parameter
        // to avoid having to use Expression Visitor
        Condition = this.GetCondition(parameter, ownerKey),
        Priority = index
    }).Aggregate((accumulated, nextPriorityExpression) => {
        // How can I aggregate the conditions together
        Expression.Condition(nextPriorityExpression, nextPriorityExpression.Priority,  )
    });
}

protected BinaryExpression GetCondition(ParameterExpression parameter, guid ownerKey)
{
    // x => x.OwnerGlobalIdRowKey
    var property = Expression.Property(parameter, 
        nameof(IConfigurationValue.OwnerGlobalIdRowKey));

    // x => x.OwnerGlobalIdRowKey == { valueOf(ownerKey) }
    return Expression.Equal(property, Expression.Constant(ownerKey, 
        typeof(Guid)));
}
```

How can I to continue propagated the ternary chain of through the aggregate function?

Comment: Can you show the code you are attempting to build? I am not sure `Aggregate` is what you need? You aren't doing anything with the result of your `Aggregate` expression?

Comment: @NetMage there’s an example in the summary comment above the first function

Comment: Your comment won't compile - what is after the trailing `:`?

Comment: Also, how can you convert `guid ownerKey` to `GlobalEntityKey<IGlobalId>`?

Comment: @NetMage sorry that’s suppose to say guid we have a layer on top of EF to type keys

Comment: @NetMage oops sorry last if it’s none then it should be int.MaxValue, basically of the key is on the array it’s sorted by the order of the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the (potential) type errors in the return of `GetCondition`, you can accumulate the body of the nested ternary operators in `Aggregate` with proper typing, and then build a lambda:

```
Expression<Func<IConfigurationValue, int>> GetOrderByExpression(
    Guid[] ownerKeyByPriority) {

    // x =>
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IConfigurationValue));
    var body = ownerKeyByPriority.Select((ownerKey, index) => new {
        // Hack: Build the expressions using the same parameter
        // to avoid having to use Expression Visitor
        Test = this.GetCondition(parameter, ownerKey),
        Priority = Expression.Constant(index)
    }).Aggregate((Expression)Expression.Constant(int.MaxValue), (accumulated, nextPriorityExpression) =>
        Expression.Condition(nextPriorityExpression.Test, nextPriorityExpression.Priority, accumulated)
    );

    return (Expression<Func<IConfigurationValue, int>>)Expression.Lambda(body, parameter);
}
```

Comment: Interesting,  I was a bit confused because by default the priority would be reversed, but technically the expressions should be equivalent.  I don't have my work computer infront of me, but this makes sense.  I didn't know there was an overload with the Seed until you used it, (I don't use aggregate that often).  I'm not at my work computer but logically this code makes sense, I'm going to give you the check,  It should would if not I'll update the answer accordingly

Comment: If you wanted the conditions reverse so a higher priority is tested earlier, you could put in a call to `Reverse()` before the `Aggregate`.

Comment: Thanks,  I was just explaining my thought process on why I was originally confused, this all makes sense

Comment: Well I didn't know if it was possible for multiple conditions to evaluate true, in which case order could matter.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing an extension method that works with properties and simple expressions

```
public static Expression<Func<TEntity, int>> GetOrderByArrayPriorityExpression<TEntity, TValue>(this Expression<Func<TEntity, TValue>> selectorExpression, TValue[] orderedValues)
{       
    var body = orderedValues.Select((value, index) => new {
        //Note: Build the expressions using the same parameter to avoid having to use Expression Visitor
        //x => x.Property == {value}
        Condition = Expression.Equal(selectorExpression.Body, Expression.Constant(value, typeof(TValue))),
        Priority = Expression.Constant(index)
    }).Aggregate((Expression)Expression.Constant(int.MaxValue), (accumulated, nextPriorityExpression) =>

        //This generates the conditions (in reverse which is also fine)
        // x =>
        // x.Property == {GlobalOwnerGuid} ? 3 : 
        // x.Property == {ClientOwnerGuid} ? 2 :
        // x.Property == {CompanyOwnerGuid} ? 1 :
        // x.Property == {DivisionOwnerGuid} ? 0 : Int.MaxValue
        Expression.Condition(nextPriorityExpression.Condition, nextPriorityExpression.Priority, accumulated)
    );

    // reuse to original parameter to avoid using an expression visitor
    return (Expression<Func<TEntity, int>>)Expression.Lambda(body, selectorExpression.Parameters);
}
```